# How to implement search button to android Firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-search

I tried so many time to implement to search my android Firebase database.
Query: `query = dateRef.orderByChild("phone").equalTo(searchPhoneNumber);`
I don't know how to set searchPhoneNumber in EditText  value. But I know EditText and one button using to search phone numbers. But I need Java code. Eg: if I enter phone numbers in EditText and I press button, after I get a output in same page.
Here I attached my Firebase screenshot and my code.

**Firebase database screenshot**

[image]

**java**

```
public class ViewProduction extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private Adapater mAdapter;

private ProgressBar mprogress;

private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
private List<Datastore> mUploads;


EditText edit;
Button btnsearch;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_production);


    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    edit =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);

    btnsearch = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsearch);



    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("Production Details");

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerj);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mprogress = findViewById(R.id.progress);

    mUploads = new ArrayList<>();

    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Rajadriving");

    btnsearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // called search() method on button click.
            search();
        }
    });

public void search(){
    edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

            DatabaseReference dateRef = rootRef.child("Rajadriving").child("9-6-2018");
            Query query = dateRef.orderByChild("phone").equalTo(s.toString());

            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Datastore upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Datastore.class);
                        mUploads.add(upload);
                    }
                    mAdapter = new Adapater(ViewProduction.this, mUploads);

                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    mprogress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(ViewProduction.this, databaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mprogress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}





@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home){
        this.finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.udayaj.rajadriving.ViewProduction">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/progress"
    android:hint="enter phone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnsearch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/recyclerj"
    android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edit"
    android:text="Search" />


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/table01"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerj">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why in Firebase query you are using `searchPhoneNumber` as String object? I think it should be as variable in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you.

Use `Textwatcher()` to implement search functionality.how to implement given below.

```
btnsearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       // called search() method on button click.
       search();
    }
});

public void search(){
        edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

                DatabaseReference dateRef = rootRef.child("Rajadriving").child("9-6-2018");
                Query query = dateRef.orderByChild("phone").equalTo(s.toString());

                query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Datastore upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Datastore.class);
                            mUploads.add(upload);
                        }
                        mAdapter = new Adapater(ViewProduction.this, mUploads);

                        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        mprogress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Toast.makeText(ViewProduction.this, databaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mprogress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: firstly what error you got? please comment out your DatabaseReference and query listener code and add above search() method and called search() method on button click. and add phone as input in edittext .I hope this will help you.

Comment: btnsearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                                search();
            }       });~ this line error

Comment: are you added button in layout? if not then add it.

Comment: are you added button in activity_view_production in this layout.

Comment: I added my Java and xml file.

Comment: mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerj);  please change with 
 mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id. recyclerji) in code your id different.

Comment: I got a error : illegal start to expression. In btnsearch. Setonclicklistener closed curly brackey.

Comment: I got a output. But button is not working. I enter the phone in edittext then I hit the enter after only I got a result.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
Query query = dateRef.orderByChild("phone").equalTo("searchPhoneNumber");
```

to

```
Query query = dateRef.orderByChild("phone").equalTo(searchPhoneNumber);
```

See, no quotation marks? You need to search the database after the value that your variable `searchPhoneNumber` holds and not after the searchPhoneNumber **String** which is obvious is not a phone number.